# How to upload data to S3 as Multipart file while getting data in loopDoWhile EIP from Paginated API using Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel

I am  getting data from a paginated API in loopDoWhile , Since the whole data is huge so we are reading it page by page from paginated API.

I want to upload all this data  received from all pages of paginated API to be uploaded as single file in s3 (Multipart file).

Could you please let me know how can we achieve this through Camel.